# How to open the sketch file in windows

Tags: android, photoshop, sketchapp

I have downloaded the icon set from google.
https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines

It has the .SKETCH file. I need to know how to open the file. I have Photoshop and Sketchup 2016.

can anyone assist me to open the file ?

Also if possible please let me know the location of google icon set in .fla or .psd format

Answer (score 6):

For those who have same problem - Icons8 have just released a free tool for opening .sketch files in Windows: https://icons8.com/lunacy.

You can copy CSS of any object and copy plain text for any text layer.
We plan to implement for features soon.

Comment: Thank you! This works good in MacOS too!

Answer (score 3):

The .SKETCH extension relates to Sketch (https://www.sketchapp.com/). If you're on a Mac, this is dead simple to download, and install.

If you're not on a Mac, **Avocode** and **Zeplin** claim to allow you to open the files on any OS, but I've had limited success (you'll have to Google the Application URLs, I don't have enough rep points, yet).

Failing that, Illustrator, Photoshop and GIMP are able to open the SVG and EPS files, and just about anything can open the PNGs.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend **Figma**, I tried all app mentioned in other answers, Figma was the best for me.

Disclaimer: I do not work nor develop Figma.